# Assign a pandas series to a groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, group-by

This is my question after a long time!! I've searched other Q&A on StackOverflow but didn't find any useful answer to my question.

I have a pandas DataFrame with columns such as

```
|---------------------|------------------|  
|      date           |     Prediction   |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|       2014-01-01    |         0.0      |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|       2014-01-01    |         0.0      |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|       2014-01-02    |         0.0      |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|       2014-01-02    |         0.0      |  
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I want to set the values (using groupby operation on `date` column) in the cells of `Prediction` column instead of 0. For that suppose my prediction is a dataframe `x` with two values

```
|---------------------|------------------|  
|      date           |       yhat       |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|       2014-01-01    |         2.0      |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|       2014-01-02    |         3.0      |  
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I'm trying to do as below `df.groupby('date', as_index=False)['Prediction'] = x['yhat']`

but it is throwing me an error:

> TypeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object does not support item assignment

My expectation of the output is :

```
|---------------------|------------------|  
|      date           |     Prediction   |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|       2014-01-01    |         2.0      |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|       2014-01-01    |         2.0      |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|       2014-01-02    |         3.0      |  
|---------------------|------------------|  
|       2014-01-02    |         3.0      |  
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Since the grouped operation is essentially two-row dataframe, I am expecting it to work since `x` is also a pandas dataframe with 2 values.

Any suggestions to achieve this are highly appreciated.

**EDIT**
I have more dates in my dataframe (than shown in the above example). I need to fill Prediction column values only for specific dates (not all dates).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a `join()` operation. For example:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Prediction': [0, 0, 0, 0]},
                    index=['2014-01-01', '2014-01-01', '2014-01-02', '2014-01-02'])
vals = pd.DataFrame({'yhat': [2, 3]}, index=['2014-01-01', '2014-01-02'])
result = data.join(vals)
result
#             Prediction  yhat
# 2014-01-01           0     2
# 2014-01-01           0     2
# 2014-01-02           0     3
# 2014-01-02           0     3
```

But now the columns are not exactly what you'd want them to be. So we'll drop the original `Prediction` and rename `yhat`:

```
result.drop('Prediction', axis=1).rename({'yhat': 'Prediction'}, axis=1)
#             Prediction
# 2014-01-01           2
# 2014-01-01           2
# 2014-01-02           3
# 2014-01-02           3
```